# useState - do not rerender the state is set with the same object content

Tags: reactjs, jsx

In `useState` if we assign the object of same content, it keeps rerendering, is there a way to prevent it? Below it keeps log "haha" though the `bg` content is the same.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [bg, setBG] = useState({ hello: "a" });

  const makeRed = () => {
    setBG({ ...bg });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {console.log("haha")}
      <button onMouseMove={makeRed}>make Red</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

see [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-cache-1t34v1?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem with the spread operator

```
setBG({ ...bg });
```

Every time you call it, it instantiates a new object which is considered as a new state (not the same object value as you expected)

For the fix, you should call it like below to always refer to the same object

```
setBG(bg);
```

Full modification

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [bg, setBG] = useState({ hello: "a" });

  const makeRed = () => {
    //always refer to the same object
    setBG(bg);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {console.log("haha")}
      <button onMouseMove={makeRed}>make Red</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-monad-wpg35f?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for that is you are creating a different object with a different memory address. (even though the object's values look the same.)
Sometimes you can not avoid making a new object using a destructor or other methods.

in that case, you can check the equality of objects in the `setState` callback method. you can return the existing state if you see both objects are the same. (even though memory addresses are different)

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef } from "react";
import _isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';

export default function App() {
  const [bg, setBG] = useState({ hello: "a" });

  const makeRed = () => {
    setBG(_bg => {
      // checking the equality
      if (_isEqual(_bg, bg)) {
        return _bg
      }
      return bg;
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      {console.log("haha")}
      <button onMouseMove={makeRed}>make Red</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because in js `{...bg}` !== `{...bg}`, when you set another `{...bg}` js language determined it is different.

```js
const bg = { hello: "a" }
console.log({...bg} !== {...bg}) //Output: true
```